# Correct way to have a multilangiage blog with article translation

Tags: php, wordpress, html

I have my non-wordpress blog in English and now I need to have the same blog in French and Spanish. I not only need menu buttons, breadcrumbs, etc but also the actual content of the articles too. So when users choose "Spanish" from the top bar, they will see my blog in Spanish, including the articles translated.

I was thinking about using .pot files. But articles body contents are generally long and I am not even sure if I could accomplish this with .pot

Make a subdomain/subdirectory for each new language. But if in the future I decide to support other languages, it will be crazy to maintain. Ie, if I need to change the logo I would have to change the logo in all subdirectory/subdomain websites.

What is the best way to accomplish multilanguage site?

Thank you

Comment: multi lingual. And you should at all times avoid redundancy. I would suggest a simple database trick, where you add a language column and when selecting articles you make sure to select out from the specified language. However, this is not really a programming related question.

Comment: Maybe you should consider using Google Translate? ... They have script sample for translate an entire page

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have properly outlined main problems raising in the process of creating and maintaining multilingual website. All of this problems are solved by [WPML - Wordpress Multilingual Plugin](https://wpml.org). It is most popular, very flexible and powerful system for translating websites.